# Missing a reference to AsyncCtpLibrary.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have installed API for using new feature of C# 5 but some strange things happens.

i am able to use async keyword but VS 2010 tell me that "Can not find Task-Related types.Are u missing to a reference to AsynCtpLibrary.dll ?"

And also i see some errors on compile time like " compiler required member  'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilder.Create'"

Where is AsyncCtpLibrary.dll ? It fix my problem to add it to reference ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default I think is in "C:\Users\@user@\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples" and yes, adding it will fix your problem.

Comment: Microsoft didn't choose the best place to put the DLL's - the samples folder.

Comment: Do You know if is official now? 2015 year now, but don't see this library included