# Using C# 5 async feature in Linqpad

Tags: c#, asynchronous, linqpad, c#-5.0

Is it possible to use C# 5 async features in Linqpad snippets? Does anyone know of any hack/beta which allows you to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Installing the async CTP should be enough - async code should compile in LINQPad (although the Intellisense will show red squigglies). I'll look at dealing to the red squigglies in the next beta :)

You will have to [add a reference to asyncctplibrary.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169108/missing-a-reference-to-asyncctplibrary-dll), as in VS.

Update: the red squigglies and autocompletion has been dealt to in the [latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx).