# Unable to use async/await in LINQPad - "Invalid token {after async} in .."

Tags: c#, async-await, linqpad

I wanted to try the "new" `async/await` (yeah, I'm late to the party) so I fired up LINQPad 4.5.1 which is currently the latest non-beta. After switching to "C# Program" and input the following code, sans comment;

```cs
// "Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"
// - But compiles with `async` removed
async void foo () {
}

void Main()
{
    foo();
}
```

But it .. "doesn't work" as indicated.

This error seems to indicate that LINQPad is using C#4 and not C#5 although the website does say "LINQPad supports everything *in C# 5.0* and Framework 4.x" and [others don't seem to have this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893882/using-c-sharp-5-async-feature-in-linqpad).

What causes this error, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was .. silly of me. The current machine had .NET 4 - *not* 4.5 - installed.

After installing .NET 4.5 "it works".

Answer (score 3):

**Even if this is not the solution for this particular issue**, it may come handy for people like me that arrived to this question looking a fix for a compile error with the `Task<T>` return type because I was missing a using. The way to add it on LinqPad is pressing `F4` > `Namespace Imports` tabs and adding at the bottom of the list `System.Threading.Tasks` then press `Ok`.

You can also set this new list as the default for the new queries pressing `Set as default for new queries`

[image: Go by shortcut]

Other way to access this tab is by the top menu `Query` > `Namespace Imports`

[image: Go by the query menu]

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with the poster, people with the issue of trying to run async in Linqpad get this as the first question, and this has helped me.