# Asynchronous HttpHandlers and WriteAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, httphandler

I've been experimenting with some code code on Ayende Rahien's blog [here](http://ayende.com/blog/72705/node-cs) which demonstrates using asynchronous HttpHandlers to improve the number of requests that can be processed concurrently.

Unfortunately I can get even the basic example to work. I'm getting the following error:

> 'System.IO.TextWriter' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAsync'
>   and no extension method 'WriteAsync' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.IO.TextWriter' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

for the line.

```
return context.Response.Output.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
```

I would imagine the method is an extension method added in net4 as part of the Parallel Extensions however for the life of me I can find the correct namespace.

Wouls any of you hardcore csharpers please shed the light.

Comment: @Alixx: That nailed it cheers! Stick it down in an answer and the points are yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx  (under update 1) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Might set you on the right line

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at both Scott Hanselman and Ayende's blog and was scratching my head proper.

My solution was to install the Async CTP and to include a reference to AsyncCtpLibrary
which is well hidden in my case 
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples

Kudos to [Missing a reference to AsyncCtpLibrary.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169108/missing-a-reference-to-asyncctplibrary-dll)