# Custom handler processes multiple requests serially and not simultaneouslly

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

Created a custom handler and behaves as my title states, but I need parallel processing of requests. This handler asks to a second machine for html content, images and other web page related content. But as every request gets kind of "queued" the result is a very slow response of content. Web browsers are able to send multiple requests at the same time, but this "problem" reduces it to a single request.

I've verified this behavior logging the begging and ending of the handler. Never a  request starts before the previous ends.

Also logged global.asax Application_BeginRequest event, and note that this event is called as fast as the request is received. The problem is somehow between the fire of this event and the invocation of my handler.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390491/asynchronous-httphandlers-and-writeasync) any help?

Comment: If you have include session on your call, then maybe this is the reason. Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session/9427550#9427550

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you stated, and doing some more research, the Session gets lock in every request so basically all is processed serially :(

Thank you guys and a Happy New Year !

Comment: FYI: was using IHttpHandler. I gave a chance to IHttpAsyncHandler but this also locks the Session.