# Unable to disable lock on Session (maybe)

Tags: asp.net, session-state

After a previous post about an issue with Session State being locked on every request (normal behavior for Asp.Net), tried fully disabling Session State (). This, in fact, disables the Session object and throws exceptions if try to use it. However, as stated in the named post, all requests are still serviced in a serialized fashion. This is, a second "simultaneous" request doesn't get served till previous gets finished served. Related documentation states that disabling Session State avoids the lock in the session but, in my case, my requests are still serviced serially.

This is not MVC.

This is my previous post [Custom handler processes multiple requests serially and not simultaneouslly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846794/custom-handler-processes-multiple-requests-serially-and-not-simultaneouslly)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having exact same problem. Actually, i tried on MVC app as well. What i am doing is creating empty App with just one Page/Controller and putting Thread.Sleep() to PageLoad|Index method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this always happens inside the developer environment (cassini). When dissabling session state there is no possible access to the Session object but it seems to exists a lock request somewhere.

Debugging in IIS this doesn't happen.

Hope this help.